# bash script load an modify array from external file

Tags: bash, text-processing, array

I have written a script that is reading an array: **recentdirs** with directory names from an external config file called: **defaults.cfg** and the user can either chose one of the directories from the list or enter a new one. If the user enters a new directory I want this to be stored as the first position in the array **recentdirs** and saved back in the config file **defaults.cfg** . The script is able to do this BUT in the current form it is overwriting the file **defaults.cfg** and thus loosing all other values I'd like to store in it. I have played with ">>" but then the array will be added to the end of the file instead of modified.

directory_select.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
number=0

source defaults.cfg

for i in "${recentdirs[@]}"
do
   #only show the last 5 directories
    if [ $number -le 5 ]
    then
            echo "$number - $i"
            number=$((number+1))
    else
            break
    fi
done

read selection

#check if number or string was entered
regpat='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $selection =~ $regpat ]]
then
    newdir=( ${selection} )

    #merge arrays to have the new entry at the first position
    recentdirs=("${newdir[@]}" "${recentdirs[@]}")

    #write array back into file
    set | grep ^recentdirs > defaults.cfg
else
    echo ${recentdirs[$selection]}
fi
```

Content of defaults.cfg

```
recentdirs=([0]="/new/folder/" [1]="/folderA/folder1/" [2]="/folderB/folder2/" [3]="/folderX/folder5")
```

EDIT
Working version:

```
#!/bin/bash
number=0
source defaults.cfg

for i in "${recentdirs[@]}"
do
   #only show the last 5 directories
    if [ $number -le 5 ]
    then
            echo "$number - $i"
            number=$((number+1))
    else
            break
    fi
done

read selection

#check if number or string was entered
regpat='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $selection =~ $regpat ]]
then
    newdir=( ${selection} )

    #merge and write array back into file with sed
    sexp="s[^recentdirs.*[recentdirs=(${newdir[@]} ${recentdirs[@]})["
    sed -i -e "$sexp" defaults.cfg

else
    echo ${recentdirs[$selection]}
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace

```
grep ^recentdirs > defaults.cfg
```

with

```
sexp="s[^recentdirs.*[recentdirs=(${newdir[@]} ${recentdirs[@]})["
sed -i -e "$sexp" defaults.cfg
```

Comment: Thank you for that fast solution. May I ask you why you chose **[** as the sed delimiter? I though one should choose a delimiter that is not within the pattern?

Comment: Yes, I used '[' instead of the usual '/' delimiter in sed command since the latter would conflict with '/' in directories path.